# Width of a UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm creating a UITableView and I need the cells to be of UITableViewCellStyleValue2, that's to say a right-aligned label on the left hand side, like those on the Contacts App.

It works fine but I would like this label to have more width in order to fit the text I want to display.

I haven't find anything on the iOS documentation so is it possible at all? if yes, how? I wonder if I missed something on the search.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to implement your custom UITableViewCell. Take a look at http://zcentric.com/2008/08/05/custom-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score 1):

as @lluismontero suggests, custom cells give you the most flexibility and are not overly complicated.

if you do want to customize the default cells you can in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` add subviews to the `contentView` of the default cell after it has been created. You can add any subviews you like so you can add your own right aligned `UILabel` and don't use the built-in `detailTextLabel`.

EDIT: remove the suggestion to use 'tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` as the frame is set after this method

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but doesn´t really work. I was hoping to avoid adding more subviews, but I think it will be the fastest way after all.

Comment: yeah, my mistake. I forgot that frame properties are set by the tableView after `tableView:willDisplayCell:ForRowAtIndexPath:`. You need to add a subview.